# how to read text file on any machine in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read file,but it is reading only on my machine,it is not working on another machine.Here is my code..

```
FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream("/path of myfile/User.txt");    
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String str;
while ((str =  br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Please help me,how to read file on another machine as well,what changes should I make?

Comment: First you need to point to the correct path. A network share path for example. Second, you need to ensure your user account has permissions to access the file on the network.

Comment: What do you mean another machine? You copy your file with programm to another PC and try to read or you want to read files from your local line?

Comment: what is not working? do you have some "strange" letters in the text? it would be an encoding problem, you should choose your encoding explicitly.

Comment: The `DataInputStream` is completely redundant. You need only to construct the `InputStreamReader` on the `FileInputStream`. Also, you forgot to specify the encoding for the `InputStreamReader`, so it will use the platform default (that is, a random) encoding, which is double-plus ungood.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing that you already found a way to share the file, either with HTTP, FTP, SMB or NFS, but you've some problems, perhaps some funny characters appearing in the text. If you don't name the encoding that you want to use, the default one for the machine will be used, and if they have different defaults, you'll run into problems.

Choose an encoding when writing and reading, for example for UTF8 universal encoding, your source should be modified as:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
```

When you write your file, of course, you've to use the same encoding, for instance:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/path of myfile/User.txt");
 OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file that resides on another machine, you have to serve that file using some kind of network server, like an http-server or an smb-server.